# How to append time stamp to a string in Python 2.7 in aws lambda?

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, rds

I'm trying to create RDS MySQL DB snapshot using aws lambda function. I want to create db snapshot name with time stamp (not snapshot creation time).
Example: For below code I'm expecting 'mydb-2017-08-24-06-12' as a db snapshot name.

```
import boto3
import datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('rds')
    i = datetime.datetime.now()
    response = client.create_db_snapshot(
    DBSnapshotIdentifier="mydb" % (i),
    DBInstanceIdentifier='mydb'
)
```

but it throwing below error:
DBSnapshotIdentifier="mydb" % (i),
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

**Please provide any type of relevant solution to me.**

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed my code like this:

```
import boto3
import datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('rds')
    x = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("mydb-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
    response = client.create_db_snapshot(
    DBSnapshotIdentifier= x,
    DBInstanceIdentifier='mydb'
)
```

Comment: Folks, I wrote the solution code to my question. Advantage of this code is, It will create the manual snapshot to your database. AWS people already providing automatic snapshots but those will be expire after 35 days, If you taken manual snapshots those will never expire.Please ask me if you have any questions..